# Calling method from MVC "Controller to WEB API Controller" Asynchronous?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

Hi i am basically doing a Mobile Website in MVC 4 and a WEP API within one project. The mobile website will have access and features to control the backend WEP API.

The end users will use native mobile app.

My problem: The web api handles a array containing items of information. Now i want to run a thread emptying the array(queue), any suggestions on how is the most feasible way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

If need to make a Fire and Forget call to a Web Api running in the backend with that array. You can use the HttpClient library, which already provides a Task based model for doing async calls, and use something like this in the MVC controller action

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => client.PostAsync(...));
```